# Quarkus multi-module Maven project with integration tests, problems with including quarkus-maven-plugin multiple times, for each module?

Tags: maven, quarkus, multi-module

At work I'm splitting up an existing Quarkus application into several modules:

- three "application modules" `A`, `B` and `C` containing controllers/API endpoints
- a single `shared` module for shared code and database access
- a `deployment` module that bundles all modules together for deployment

The idea is that I can combine different versions of `A`, `B` and `C` in production (perhaps I am not ready to deploy my changes to `A` to production, even though I want to deploy the changes in `B` now).

Strictly speaking, the `quarkus-maven-plugin` is only required for the `deployment` module because that is the only module that I will want to run as a Quarkus application.

However, because each of the application modules is responsible for a set of endpoints, it seems logical to put the integration tests (`@QuarkusTest`s) for those in the application modules themselves. However, this will require the `quarkus-maven-plugin` for each of the modules, only for the purpose of being able to run the integration tests.

Are there any adverse effects of doing this?

An alternative I'm considering is to put the integration tests for each application module in seperate modules (`A-tests`, `B-tests` and `C-tests`) and include the `quarkus-maven-plugin` in *those*. Is that better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved but it is not straight forward.

The following tasks have to be done

1. Create Multi Module Maven project where

   - deployable and non-deployable (shared) modules should be configured differently
   - shared modules should be allowed to use as dependency in other modules
2. Write tests where

   - Each module should contain their own tests
   - Test classes must be shared
   - Integration tests of shared modules should run during the deployable module's integration test phase

At first, I have to clarify this

> the  `quarkus-maven-plugin`  is only required for the  `deployment`  module because that is the only module that I will want to run as a Quarkus application.

One of the most important concept of Quarkus to favor build time work over runtime. That's why `quarkus-maven-plugin` does much more than just build deployable artifact. So, this plugin is always required by each module wheter that module is deployable or not.

### Create Multi Module Maven project

Let's say there are three modules (four `pom.xml` files)

- **-parent* - An aggregator which contains common settings, plugin templates, dependencies used by all submodules, etc.
- **-module-[a-z]* - application modules contains business logic, endpoints, shared entities. There modules are **not deployable artifacts**.
- **-deployment* - Deployable Quarkus application which can use other modules as dependencies, can contain other business logic and / or endpoints, entities, whatever.

#### aggregator

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.github.zforgo</groupId>
    <artifactId>so-78088326-quarkus-multi-module-testing-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.12.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>3.8.1</quarkus.platform.version>
        <skipITs>true</skipITs>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.2.5</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>so-78088326-module-a</module>
        <module>so-78088326-module-b</module>
        <module>so-78088326-deployment</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test-jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-code</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate-code</goal>
                                <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>build-deployable-app</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <compilerArgs>
                            <arg>-parameters</arg>
                        </compilerArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner
                            </native.image.path>
                            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

There are two remarkable things in the `<pluginManagement>`section.

1. The `maven-jar-plugin` configured to create another artifact which contains test classes (more precisely all classes and resources under test folder). This configuration allows us to share even integration tests between other modules.
2. The `quarkus-maven-plugin` configured a little differently than as usual. The `build` goal moved under another `<execution>` section and got an `<id>`tag. From now, the `build` (which creates a deployable artifact) goal can be eliminated when it is needed,

#### non-deployable application modules

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>io.github.zforgo</groupId>
        <artifactId>so-78088326-quarkus-multi-module-testing-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>so-78088326-module-a</artifactId>
    <properties>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-deployable-app</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

A non-deployable Quarkus module can be referenced as a dependency, it can be started during the test phase but it cannot be started like a standalone Quarkus application. By binding the `build-deployable-app` execution to the `none` lifecycle phase, `quarkus:build` goal will be disabled.

**Don't forget** to make these modules discoverable to the main (deployable) module's CDI bean discovery mechanism by [configuring `jandex-maven-plugin`](https://quarkus.io/guides/maven-tooling#multi-module-maven) or by adding a `beans.xml` to every non-deployable submodules.

### <s>deployment</s> deployable module

In the Quarkus ecosystem the deployment module means totally different. Every Quarkus extension has a `deployment` submodule that handles build time processing and so on.

In this case a deployment module has to be build as a deployable Quarkus application using other submodules and probably some own code (e.g. other Rest endpoint)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>io.github.zforgo</groupId>
        <artifactId>so-78088326-quarkus-multi-module-testing-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>so-78088326-deployment</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- ... -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>so-78088326-module-a</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>so-78088326-module-b</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here, the `build` goal of  `quarkus-maven-plugin` enabled and bound to `package` lifecycle phase by default.

### Write, share and run tests

Let's say every module has own tests. Every test class that annotated with `@QuarkusTest` should run during the submodule's `test` phase, but the `@QuarkusIntegrationTest`s should be shared and run during `integration-test` phase of deployment module.

#### Share tests between modules

In the aggregator module `maven-jar-plugin` has already configured to create test jar artifact. These artifacts are available like:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>so-78088326-module-a</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>
```

#### Enable / disable integration tests

In the aggreagator module the integration tests disabled by default by using `<skipITs>true</skipITs>` property. Well, disabling the skipping of integration test will enable them, won't it? In the deployment module `skipITs` property has to be set to `false`

#### Run integration tests from dependent modules

In order to run integration tests from external artifacts the `maven-failsafe-plugin` has to be configured properly. The `dependenciesToScan` parameter allows to specify and execute integration tests from dependencies.

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration combine.children="append">
       <dependenciesToScan>
           <dependency>${project.groupId}:so-78088326-module-a:test-jar</dependency>
           <dependency>${project.groupId}:so-78088326-module-b:test-jar</dependency>
       </dependenciesToScan>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Important!** All those included dependencies must already be defined in `<dependencies>`

For further options see the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html#tests-from-dependencies).

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth reply! If you don't mind, I have some follow-up questions. You mention that "That's why quarkus-maven-plugin does much more than just build deployable artifact." Can you explain what else it does (beside generating the subclasses to make CDI work)? Where can I read more about that? I discovered that my application seems to work fine if only the `deployment`-module has the Quarkus plugin (except the integration tests, of course). What am I missing that I am not noticing? I also discovered that in all approaches, live reloading doesn't seem to work. Any way to repair?

Comment: Many years and major versions ago `quarkus-maven-plugin` was required in the submodules. Now it is no longer requred. But if other goals (`generate-code` and `generate-code-tests`) already ran when building it allows you to start submodules in dev mode by running `mvn quarkus:build quarkus:dev` in the submodule's folder. That's funny. 
If you only need to enable CDI bean discover then it's enough to put a beans.xml (or configure `jandex-maven-plugin`) in the submodules but `quarkus-maven-plugin` is no longer required. IMHO to be able to start just a submodule in dev mode can be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! Should, in your experience, live reloading work for all modules or is that something I should learn to live without?